# Prophet don't work for a specific case (normal_lpdf: Location parameter[1] is -nan(ind), but must be finite!)

Tags: python, stan, facebook-prophet

Currently I'm running a time series model with Prophet. Then I filter a data set and make a future predictions, generally it's run without problems, but when I filter a specific data in the data frame it show an error.

```
WARNING:fbprophet:Optimization terminated abnormally. Falling back to Newton.

RuntimeError: Exception: normal_lpdf: Location parameter[1] is -nan(ind), but must be finite!
```

I'm using a logistic growth. The model runs with most of the filters, but with some of these filters specifically, it doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest adding more sample data, though I'm experiencing this issue, my data is rather privacy sensitive, and I don't know how to recreate the problem otherwise. 

I have noticed if I don't filter out outliers that my output will be crazily unreliable. So maybe tweak your outlier settings?